# Laravel Search Keyword Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So currently I've created search text field to find keywords for specific columns of my database.

Using this eloquent

```
$data = DB::table('product')
        ->select('product.id','product.title','product.description','product.content','product.photo','product.quantity','product.price')
        ->join('product_per_category','product_per_category.product_id','=','product.id')
        ->where(['product.deleted' => 0])
        ->where(['product_per_category.deleted' => 0])
        ->where(['product_per_category.productcategory_id' => $id])
        ->where(function($query) use ($keyword){
            $query->where('product.content', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('product.title', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('product.quantity', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('product.price', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
        })
        ->groupBy('product.id')
        ->paginate(10);
```

If I try to search `234.00` value of Price all possible value that will match with the columns of `content, title, quantity, price, quantity` will automatically return the data.

How ever if I tried to search for a keyword like this

`234.00 Books` value of `Price` and `Title`. it will not return any data now. Because it will match only this sentence on specific columns.

What I'm trying to do is if I search something like this

= `234.00 Books 20`

`*Value of Price, Title and Quantity`

It should return all the data that will match on every columns. Whether the letters lowercase or uppercase as long as it matches the position of letters

Is that possible?

** UPDATE **

Objective : Just want to match the `234` value on any columns. Be the result. But the problem of my query is, if I add another keyword like `234 Books` it doesnt return any data

Comment: It is possible by regex extract from string values to variables. Or different method should be explode string in php by " " (space) and do loop for each keyword where. In your method will be 234.00 , Books, 20 as separate values to search in that columns.

Comment: the problem will be how do you know if the user meant 234 as the price or quantity etc.

Comment: Just want to match the 234 value on any columns. Be the result. But the problem of my query is, if I add another keyword like `234 Books` it doesnt return any data

Comment: okey so you will need to somehow specify a ruling how the input has to be separated. If you have such a ruling you can implement the method posted below

Comment: what mysql `engine` do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:**
Extract the keywords:

```
$delimeter = ' '; //or your separator
$keywords = explode($delimeter, $search); // Will return an array containing each keyword
```

**Then:** Loop over each keyword and call your search query or expand your query dynamically

**Example**
Something like this should work...

```
$base_query = DB::table('product')
        ->select('product.id','product.title','product.description','product.content','product.photo','product.quantity','product.price')
        ->join('product_per_category','product_per_category.product_id','=','product.id')
        ->where(['product.deleted' => 0])
        ->where(['product_per_category.deleted' => 0])
        ->where(['product_per_category.productcategory_id' => $id]);

foreach($keywords as $keyword){
       $base_query->where(function($query) use ($keyword){
            $query->where('product.content', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('product.title', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('product.quantity', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('product.price', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
            })
}

$result = $base_query->get();
```

You will need to do a loop because you don't know the amount of keywords in your search result

Answer (score 1):

You can use [explode PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like this:

```
$keywords = explode(' ', $keyword); // Will return an array containing each keyword
dd($keywords);
```

If your keywords can contain spaces, you may should consider using another delimiter or splitting your query parameters.